# Use VBA in power point to set bullets

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to set bullet points in Power Point VBA. I have the following working code, but it provides numbered bullets. I only want standard bullets.

Any help would be appreciated:

```
newRow.Cells(8).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = inputText ' Note this text is multi-line and of type string.
newRow.Cells(8).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Style = ppBulletCircleNumWDBlackPlain
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to change bullet type with [BulletFormat.Type property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.bulletformat.type):

```
Dim tr As TextRange
Set tr = newRow.Cells(8).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
'change to standard unordered bullet
tr.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = ppBulletUnnumbered
'align bullets
tr.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
```

Comment: Thank you very much artnib. That removed the number, but now the 2nd line of text is indented. Previously all the text was nicely aligned. Are you able to advise on that please?

Comment: In my case bullets are centered by default. I've added left alignment. Does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to maintain indentation of subsequent lines:

```
newRow.Cells(8).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character = 8226
```